# Why Guice prevents from binding to Provider?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Recently, when I played around with Google Guice I was trying to do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    ...
    bind(Provider.class).to(ViewFactory.class);
    ...
}
```

Where `ViewFactory` was:

```
public class ViewFactory implements Provider<SomeType> {...}
```

Of course, Guice didn't let me do that returing error:

```
1) Binding to Provider is not allowed.
{stacktrace}
```

What is the reason why it is not possible to bind to provider?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess it is because `Provider` interface is very special to Guice. In fact, all its internal machinery is implemented in term of providers.

Moreover, this could create ambiguities. If bindings to providers were possible:

```
bind(SomeClass.class).to(SomeClassImpl1.class);
bind(new TypeLiteral<Provider<SomeClass>>() {}).to(() -> new SomeClassImpl2());
```

then what should Guice inject here?

```
@Inject
OtherClass(Provider<SomeClass> someClassProvider) { ... }
```

Should it be a provider which returns `SomeClassImpl1` (because of the first binding; remember, direct injections and provider injections are interchangeable in Guice) or should it be a provider which returns `SomeClassImpl2` (because of the second binding)?

It really is redundant. Because you can inject `SomeClass` or `Provider<SomeClass>` regardless of the actual binding, you can bind the class itself to its provider:

```
bind(SomeClass.class).toProvider(() -> new SomeClassImpl());

// Either of the following will work
@Inject
OtherClass1(Provider<SomeClass> someClassProvider) { ... }

@Inject
OtherClass2(SomeClass someClass) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Provider` is a special case. Guice does a lot of things behind the scenes with `Provider`, so they just ban binding to the `Provider` class entirely. One example is with scoping: your custom `Provider` might call `new` every single time, but if you create the provider in the Singleton scope, that should not happen. So Guice doesn't actually inject your provider, it injects a wrapped version. Things like that is why they ban binding to `Provider.class` directly. Here's a code example:

```
import com.google.inject.*;
import com.google.inject.name.*;

public class ProviderBindExample {
  public static class ProvModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      bind(Foo.class).toProvider(FooProvider.class);
      bind(Foo.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("singleton"))
          .toProvider(FooProvider.class)
          .in(Singleton.class);
    }
  }

  public static interface Foo { }

  public static class FooProvider implements Provider<Foo> {
    @Override
    public Foo get() {
      return new Foo() {};
    }
  }

  public static class SomeClass {
    @Inject public Provider<Foo> provider;
    @Inject @Named("singleton") public Provider<Foo> singletonProvider;
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    Injector inj = Guice.createInjector(new ProvModule());
    SomeClass s = inj.getInstance(SomeClass.class);
    System.out.println("Provider class = " + s.provider.getClass());
    System.out.println("Singleton provider class = " + s.singletonProvider.getClass());

    Foo first = s.provider.get();
    Foo second = s.provider.get();

    System.out.printf("regular scope: objects are %s%n", first == second ? "the same" : "different");

    first = s.singletonProvider.get();
    second = s.singletonProvider.get();

    System.out.printf("singleton scope: objects are %s%n", first == second ? "the same" : "different");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Provider class = class com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4
Singleton provider class = class com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4
regular scope: objects are different
singleton scope: objects are the same
```